# The mechanism behind WritableStream.write and data event in Node

Tags: node.js, events, stream

I'll illustrate the problem with the following code.

**child.js** :

```
process.stdin.resume();

process.stdin.on('data', function(data) {
      process.stdout.write(data + '\n');
      process.stdout.write('world\n');
      process.stdout.write('greatings, earthlings!\n');
});
```

**parent.js** :

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

var child = spawn('node', ['child.js']);

child.stdin.write('hello');

child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      process.stdout.write('child echoed with: ' + data);
});
```

And in the **Windows cmd**, I run

```
node parent.js
```

it outputs:

```
 child echoed with: hello
 child echoed with: world
 greatings, earthlings!
```

Here I did bind the **data event** on every **child's stdout**, and I shall get echoed back in a pattern as 'child echoed with data'.
As you can see, on the third line of the outputs, it's not in that pattern. So why?

I assume one write triggers one data event(true?).

So I tried to signify when does the data event callback function end.

I changed the way I bind data event in **parent.js** with:

```
child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      process.stdout.write('child echoed with: ' + data);
      process.stdout.write('callback ends\n');
});
```

And I get this output:

```
child echoed with: hello
callback ends
child echoed with: world
greatings, earthlings!
callback ends
```

It turns out with three write, only two data events get fired?

So why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `stream` is just a stream of bytes, so it is not safe to assume there will be any correlation between the number of `write` calls and the number of `data` events. For standard implementations and usage, chances are that they will be close to the same, but it depends on how quickly you are writing the data, and how much data you are writing. For instance, one call to write could trigger a `data` event for each byte written, or some number of `write` calls could be buffered before `data` is emitted.

To be clear, what is happening in your case is this:

```
process.stdout.write(data + '\n');
// Emits 'data' event with "hello\n"

process.stdout.write('world\n');
// Doesn't emit 'data' because it is buffered somewhere.

process.stdout.write('greatings, earthlings!\n');
// Emits 'data' event with "world\ngreatings, earthlings!\n"
```

So that second event has *two* lines. Which means when you run

```
process.stdout.write('child echoed with: ' + data)
```

you are printing exactly what you see:

```
child echoed with: world\ngreatings, earthlings!\n
```

which renders as

```
child echoed with: world
greatings, earthlings!
```

Comment: Then what's triggering the data event?

Comment: The write calls will trigger data events, you are correct about that, but you cannot rely on it being one-to-one. Keep in mind that you are writing data between processes, so the timing of the events will depend on operating-system scheduling, data buffering and Node's async event processing framework.

Comment: But how do you account for that one line echoed back was not in a pattern I specified？

Comment: @Lucaz Update the answer, sorry I wasn't clearer before. The issue it emits back with two lines at once.

Comment: Now it makes sense. But still why I append another write(in child.js) in the end, it's one data event for one write call.

Comment: @Lucaz Because it is random and it can do whatever it wants.

Comment: I'm still stuck in this problem... What's deciding when the write gets buffered? I've tried to write a lot of lines of words in the first write call, if it's the buffer size that decides which write gets buffered then the data received in the parent.js should be truncated. But it didn't.

Comment: @Lucaz It depends on when the OS has scheduled the parent thread to run, and how Node's libuv callbacks pick up that there is new data to be read. Do you have a specific problem you are trying to solve with this? I would recommend opening a new question asking how to solve your problem rather than focusing on this low-level implementation.

Comment: You should read [this paragraph](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_buffering) of the stream documentation; it deals with buffering, which is the phenomenon you're likely running into.

Comment: I just started learning Node, so it's only low-level. @PaulMougel I found you don't usually do write repeatedly in Node as said by Issac in [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/nodejs/537msuD2srQ)

Comment: @Lucaz That comment from Issac is referring to multiple writes happening in parallel, not multiple `.write` calls being done like you are doing. You can call `.write` as often as you want. Internally it will buffer the data until the OS is ready to receive more data.

Comment: Well, it's strange because my computer didn't run anything expensive, and the bufferSize(highWaterMark) for `stream` is 16kb, then it's way too little of data that I `write`, why will it still buffer?

Comment: @Lucaz It could be that the child Node process ran both `.write` calls before the operating system bothered letting the parent process know that there was more data to read. Since you are working with multiple processes, nothing about this is deterministic.